# Submitting Spark Jobs in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I am trying AWS EMR to run python spark job. For submitting the job, I am using aws cli command like:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-qwertyy --steps Type=Spark,Name="SparkProgram",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--py-files,probuff.py,--packages,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4,main.py]
```

I have my EMR up and running with all the dependencies and application installed and my python code is in my local system so my question is that when I submitting the job with above command then it unable to find the python code file and gives error in steps option in console.
Please correct me if I am wrong, I am giving the path of code which is present in my local. system.

Comment: the path should be accessible by emr, the best location is s3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lamanus
Can't we use our local system file path in any way ?